# is there builtin hashmap function in Isabelle?

Tags: hashmap, isabelle

In perl there are hashes, key-value pairs. Does Isabelle/HOL have a builtin such function with the corresponding theorems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically in Isabelle/HOL, you would just use a function of type `'key ⇒ 'value`. For instance:

```
definition "num_animals 
    ≡ (λ_. 0)(''dog'' := 3, ''cat'' := 42, ''mouse'' := 12)"

lemma "num_animals ''dog'' = 3"
  by (simp add: num_animals_def)
```

Here, `(λ_. 0)` is a function that returns `0` for all input values, while the syntax `(''dog'' := 3)` modifies the existing function so that the input `dog` returns `3`.

If you want to be able to determine if a function does not contain a particular key, you can use Isabelle/HOL's `option` type:

```
definition "num_animals 
    ≡ (λ_. None)(''dog'' := Some 3, ''cat'' := Some 42, ''mouse'' := Some 12)"

lemma "num_animals ''elephant'' = None"
  by (simp add: num_animals_def)
```

There are numerous differences between this and a hash-table. For example, Isabelle will have to perform at least `O(n)` steps to look up a value in the function in this format. Also, no hashing is going on: key values are stored and compared explicitly. Usually, though, because you are *reasoning* about these things, and not typically trying to execute these things, this is not a problem.

If you are dealing with larger proof terms, you may need to look into other representations of functions, such as [Binary Search Trees](http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/BinarySearchTree.shtml) in the AFP, though these will be harder to work with.

Comment: yes, I want to reason about it, defining an environment for a programming language that stores variable values.

Comment: You can also write `''dog'' ↦ 3` as a shorthand for `''dog'' := Some 3`, and so on.

Comment: If `mapping` is a function, what is the syntax for updating it with a new key-value pair? `mapping (''key'' := value)` seems not to work.

Comment: @Gergely: It should work, but depending on its context you may need some parentheses around it: `(mapping(''key := value'')`. If you still can't get it to work, perhaps paste the error you are getting.